# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 RC fails to load several packages after reinstalling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I had to reinstall Visual Studio 2017 RC because it wasn't getting the locale configurations right after switching non-Unicode program configurations. Also, I have a broken Visual Studio 2015 in my Windows 10 system: It can't uninstall, not even repair.

While reinstalling, I kept getting many install errors from very different packages (from Office365 to NuGet). After many tries, however, I managed to somehow install it without any errors.

But upon trying to open any solution or vcxproj project I am greeted with many different errors involving different packages not loading correctly, such as:

- RestoreManagerPackage
- VSPackage
- Editor package
- NuGet package

Funny enough, now VS2017 can't open any file that has been associated with it, opening a 'migration' page in my browser, and notifying that the filetype has been rejected.

I am well aware that errors like this are quite common upon installing the latest versions of Visual Studio (from 2012 to 2015), and the most fittable and common solution would be to remove the directory `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxxxx\ComponentModelCache`.

But I'm posting this because the error recorded in ActivityLog.xml is something quite different, involving I/O errors and other processes using other files. Also, I've tested the former solution and hasn't worked at all.
I was thinking that the fact that VS2015 is still installed (and broken) might be affecting VS2017RC in some way.

[Here's the ActivityLog.xml file](http://pastebin.com/XRXSnjmD)

I found this very strange because this error happened after a fresh restart.

Also, I've tried to return to a restore point that was created shortly after the first install of VS2017 RC, but the errors persist.

**Update:** Reinstalling all VC++ Redistributables didn't work.